# Where is American English not chosen as the dialect of English taught as a second language?

Tags: english, second-lang-acquisition, american-english

Apart from countries where English is taught as a second language only to immigrants and indigenous peoples (e.g. Australia), where is American English not chosen as the dialect taught when teaching English as a second language?

I have a suspicion that in former British colonies like India, British English would be taught instead.

Comment: I don't know if I'd call it a "second language", it's complicated, but Indians learn Indian English. I guess the biggest area of agreement between BrE and InE is spelling. Apart from that, InE is a distinctive dialect because of its accent, its idioms, and its grammar.

Comment: The Indians that I know who live here (well, it is Cambridge) all speak impeccable RP-English. They would not be caught dead speaking Indian English.

Comment: Definitely in Russia they teach (still do) British standard (RP). American standard may be probably heard in some privately owned language courses, etc. But officially it's still RP.

Answer (score 4):

There is generally no single policy across different countries as to what English is taught across the board. Countries in Europe and Asia default to British English - the most popular textbooks (Headway, Matters, etc.) are based on British English. I imagine this may be different in Latin American countries - but I have no data on this.

A very common scenario around the world is American teachers teaching using British English materials. Students are also exposed to more American English through global media. Many teachers are only tangentially aware of the range of differences between the two Englishes leading to frequent confusion.

Answer (score 2):

I was taught BrE at school in the Czech Republic. I wouldn't be surprised if it was more common in Europe, simply because of geographical closeness and history.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what kind of English we were taught in Russia. It had American-style vowels, but no rotacism. I also think the spelling was British-like, but this could depend on a textbook (official and Soviet-style textbooks would use British rules definitely).

So people who went to British-speaking countries said "we were fooled in schools, they pronounce the vowels more like they are spelt than we were taught".

Comment: "we were fooled in schools, they pronounce the vowels more like they are spelt than we were taught" That happened to me after being taught Received pronunciation and then hearing common people's dialects (I now live in Britain).

Comment: American-style vowels? What did you mean?

Comment: @Alex B. American "a" in closed syllable falls to Russian "э", British "a" falls to Russian "a". American "u" (in closed syllable) falls to Russian "a", British "u" in closed syllable falls to Russian "у". We were told to pronounce the vowels America-style. And, by the way, no one yet explained to me what's the difference between how American "a" and "e" are pronounced (such as in "then" vs "than"), for me they are indistinguishable.

Comment: @Anixx "then" and "than" are a special case; many native Americans also don't distinguish them (tending toward "e"). The distinction may also be lost to some degree in a few other words such as "catch" (for me, also in "am" and "shall"). But in most words, there is a definite distinction, as in "man" vs. "men" or "batch" vs. "sketch."

Comment: @sumelic I do not know how "man" is different from "men" either. Superman is transliterated to Russian as супермен. Some other words where I see alternating spelling (indicating there is no difference): grey/gray, okey/okay.

Comment: @Anixx what did you mean by "British a falls to Russian a"???

Comment: @Anixx "a" in "man" is /æ/ in both British and American English and is neither like Russian "э" nor like Russian "a". It's a near-open front unrounded vowel, which simply doesn't exist in Russian. On the other hand, "e" in "men" is similar to Russian "э" in both American and British English.

Comment: @michau I have listened recordings and they nothing in common in American and British Englidsh. The term "near-open front unrounded vowel" is simply meaningless if you call totally different things with it. The Americans pronounce "man' and "men" the same, as Russian [э]. Superman is transliterated Супермэн in Russian. I think the Americans disambiguate man and men with mimics only.

Comment: @Anixx The same can be said about your characterisation that American "a" is like Russian "э". Ask an English native speaker and s/he will also tell you that they are two sounds that have nothing in common. By the way, IPA symbols denote ranges of possible pronunciations, so variability is expected.

Comment: @michau yes, some say they are different, but they cannot explain the difference and pronounce the same, so I think this is just a belief fueled by the spelling and difference in the meaning. Possibly even the Americans can pronounce these sounds differently to disambiguate in ambiguous context, but by default only in British English the vowels are different.

Comment: @michau "By the way, IPA symbols" - I do not know what IPA vowels mean. For me there are 5 vowels and 5 their variations, so, in total, 10 vowels. Some languages have less vowels, some also (possibly) include length (I personally do not believe but do not strongly exclude). This is the same in Russian, Ukrainian, German, Finnish, Japanese, Hebrew, Korean, Kyrgyz etc. All languages except English, the only language with unclear vowels.

Comment: @Anixx Are you trolling or what? The existence of phonemes is proved by the existence of minimal pairs. Do a simple experiment: play recordings of the American pronunciation of "[man](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/En-us-man.ogg)" and "[men](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7c/En-us-men.ogg)" several times in random order and ask native speakers of American English to identify each word. I guarantee that they will do it correctly without any problem, despite the lack of access to spelling and context.

Comment: @michau well in this case there is indeed difference, but I suspect it is because the case with these two words is ambiguous. I would transliterate them to Russian as мян and мэн respectively (or in Russian phonetic transcription, [м'ан] and [мэн]. Notice that the m in the first case is clearly palatalized. In general, this pronounciation is closer to how the British accent speakers talk. For the record, Superman or Batman are never transliterated as -мян. Батмян? Well this would sound as an Armenian surname.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47135/discussion-between-michau-and-anixx).